# JQuery show() not working after click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the next script in a webpage to show/hide the content depending on the content the user wants to see.
At the beginning all the divs show but I want the user to filter by language.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#all').click(function() {
        $(".spanish").show();
        $('.english').show();
        $('.french').show();
    });

    $('#english').click(function() {
        $('#english').addClass("current");
        $('.spanish').hide();
        $('.english').show();
        $('.french').hide();
    });

    $('#spanish').click(function(){
        $('.spanish').show();
        $('.english').hide();
        $('.french').hide();
    });

    $('#french').click(function() {
        $('.spanish').hide();
        $('.english').hide();
        $('.french').show();
    });
});
```

The filters are buttons and the sections are `<divs>`'s.
The buttons have ids with the name of the language and the div sections have a class with the name of the language.
I have tried a lot of things like `document.getElementByClassName()` and alerts but it looks like the jquery doesn't recognize the function `hide()` or `show()` after the click.
It displays `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error in the console.`

Comment: What is your HTML code? There might be an issue there, as well.

Comment: Do you only get the undefined function error when a click occurs or on page load? In the console if you type `$` does it give you the jquery object?

Comment: I see that in your code you have `$('#all')` so I have a hunch that you might have elements with multiple ID's, which is not a correct syntax. Elements can have only one ID, but multiple Classes.

Comment: Most likely that `#all` refers to a single button which clears the language filters based on the rest of OP's code

Comment: had you include reference for jquery?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: html is here:
http://www.muntcp.org.mx/test/preparatoria.html

Yes, I included reference for jquery
Yes, the $('#all') clears the language filters
The undefined function error occurs right after the click, not on page load @JonathanCrowe

Comment: for me, typing `$` in the console returns `undefined`. Typing `jQuery` gives me the jquery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 versions of jquery being loaded on your site which is the likely cause of this issue.

I recommend leaving the google hosted version of jquery and removing the other two:

```
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

The google hosted version has the added benefit of being CDN driven for faster download by your users.

With only one version of jquery running on your site you should not see these issues any longer. If for some reason you cannot remove these extra jquery libraries you could change all of your `$` to `jQuery`

for example:

```
$('.english').show()
```

becomes:

```
jQuery('.english').show()
```

Comment: The `jQuery('.english').show()` thing did the trick! 
I tried removing the other versions of jQuery but that didn't work.
I'm still not sure what was going on but anyway thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about multiple id problem.Please review your code once again.
Put an `alert` to check if it is jquery conflict.

Otherwise
try to use  `$(".spanish").css('dispaly','none');` and `$(".spanish").css('dispaly','block');`